# Initial state preparation in Quspin

Tags: quantum-state

Say we want to prepare an initial state for a one-dimensional Heisenberg spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ chain, with all spins pointing along the $+x$ direction using Quspin.

[image]

In the Quspin, one can define the initial state in terms of conserved quantities like magnetization, parity, and angular momentum quantum numbers. I am unsure how to write this state's Quspin code. Can someone please point out how it can be done?

This is my first question on this site. I hope it is not going to be downvoted.